# LM2679T-ADJ typical application circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, integrated-circuit

As mentioned in the title, I am trying to simulate the typical application circuit in the [LM2679 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2679.pdf) but for some reason, I am not getting the desired output of 5V, 5A with 12V input.

Edit:

I realized from what I read that the voltage of the capacitor doesn't matter since it is simulated.

Also, I updated my design following the steps of the adjustable datasheet

Edit 2: I need to tweak my Multisim settings for this, the issue I have now is that it takes a long time to reach 5V. This simulation gives me 1.1V in 11 seconds. Is there any way to improve upon it?

My calculations:

[image]

Datasheet circuit:

[image]

Multisim circuit:

[image]

Comment: there are multiple capacitors already

Comment: @jsotola Apologies for the typo, I meant the same type of capacitor as in the diagram.

Comment: Not clear what the problem is. In what way are your capacitors in your sim not "the same type" as in the typical application circuit?

Comment: @brhansin the circuit it mentions 15uF/50V and so on

Comment: So ... how is that different to what you use in your sim? You have 15uF caps there ...

Comment: @brhans I was under the impression that capacitor voltage matters in simulation.

Comment: In what way are you not getting what you expect? Is the output voltage wrong, or the maximum current? What exactly is not as you expect?

Comment: @SimonFitch as seen in the circuit whenever I go above 160.23 mV the software gives me an error. Also, As mentioned my target voltage and current for the output are 5V and 5A, respectively. I tried my best to follow the datasheet and calculations. I am not getting it

Answer (score 2):

You have an example for 5V0 type regulator but you are using an adjustable type regulator in the simulation with schematics for 5V regulator.

You need to change your schematics to work with the adjustable regulator instead of the fixed 5V regulator. The datasheet has an example for this.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/2ompyEr) I tried to follow the datasheet for adjustable, but it didn't work. Also, get the error after 0.256V